# Iterate in Activity within ForEach activity Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-data-factory

I have a MetaData activity and a foreach activity connected to it.

[image]

I run this ForEach activity sequentially and here is the item it iterates over:

[image]

I have a copy activity within this foreach activity:

[image]

So I have 4 childItems that I get from my meta data activity.  And I need to set the folder name in data lake based on the childItem value.  In order to access the Child Item I have to use the zero based index.  Can I set it dynamically? I assumed there would be something since it is already in a loop and is running sequentially. So I would not have to do

```
@activity('GetMetaData').output.ChildItems[3].name
```

but use the index

```
@activity('GetMetaData').output.ChildItems[index].name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#iteration-expression-language),you could refer to the properties inside the for-each activity by using `@item().XXX`,instead `@activity('GetMetaData').output.ChildItems[index].XXX`. The `items` property is the collection and each item in the collection is referred to by using the `@item()`.

> In the ForEach activity, provide an array to be iterated over for the
>   property items." Use @item() to iterate over a single enumeration in
>   ForEach activity. For example, if items is an array: [1, 2, 3],
>   @item() returns 1 in the first iteration, 2 in the second iteration,
>   and 3 in the third iteration.

Also,please see this marked answer :[Azure Data Factory get data for "For Each"component from query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608625/azure-data-factory-get-data-for-for-eachcomponent-from-query)

Comment: I had to abandon my approach but I was able to figure it out using foreach activity with @item().